# Blazor Web Assembly Андроид

Tags: c#, android, .net, blazor, webassembly

Впервые создаю проект BlazorAssembly, и хотелось бы мультиплатформеное приложение, отсюда вопрос
Подскажите как добавить проект Андроид в Blazor Assembly

Comment: Про MAUI слышали?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Звиняйте что не комментом, рейтинга мало)

Blazor WASM, на сколько я знаю, запускается полностью в браузере, так что по умолчанию является кроссплатформенным, но то ли это, что вам нужно?
Если вы хотите именно приложение с доступом к системным апи, то делайте на чём-то типа MAUI/Avalonia.

На Метанит есть [курс по MAUI](https://metanit.com/sharp/maui/) (MAUI это наследник Xamarin, если знаете о таком), на YouTube (или где вам больше нравится) есть по Avalonia. Avalonia это тот же WPF так-то, так что можете смотреть туторы и по нему.

Answer (score 0):

чтобы создать мультиплатформенное приложение, или же запустить ваш Блазор на Андроид вы можете :

1. Создать Мауи проект и внедрить ваш блазор туда как библиотеку из разор страниц, вот очень наглядное "пособие" https://www.youtube.com/live/7BDBLyADq7s?si=ioyjnHQlBQkpJosX начните смотреть с 20ой минуты
2. Так же можно попробовать Mobile Blazor Bindings, возникший в  рамках сотрудничества между командами ASP.NET Core и  .NET MAUI для создания нативных мобильных приложений https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile-blazor-bindings/
3. и еще https://www.bytehide.com/blog/blazor-desktop-like-electron-for-javascript-but-for-net